# Python: Print new lines for each item in list

Tags: python, list, printing

My list contains dates and each time after the date in the same sub-list.

```
[['2017-01-01', ['List 0', 'List 1', 'List 2']], ['2017-01-02', ['List 0', 'List 1', 'List 2']], ['2017-01-03', ['List 0', 'List 1', 'List 2']],
```

I want to make a print statement, which prints for each date a new line and for each item in the sub-list a new line like this:

[image: like in the screenshot]

I tried several things, for example:

```
def printList(self):
        print(*self.dataList, sep='\n')
```

which prints a new line for each date but I want also a new line for each item in the sublist.

Comment: Is this the part of some assignment? If not, why do you want to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give [`pprint`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pprint.html) from the standard library a try:

```
import pprint

dataList = [['2017-01-01', ['List 0', 'List 1', 'List 2']], ['2017-01-02', ['List 0', 'List 1', 'List 2']], ['2017-01-03', ['List 0', 'List 1', 'List 2']]]
pprint.pprint(dataList, width=30)
```

Result:

```
[['2017-01-01',
  ['List 0',
   'List 1',
   'List 2']],
 ['2017-01-02',
  ['List 0',
   'List 1',
   'List 2']],
 ['2017-01-03',
  ['List 0',
   'List 1',
   'List 2']]]
```

You may need to play with the `width` parameter. Also see [`pprint.pformat()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pprint.html#pprint.pformat).